# Displaying list of values using stateless components

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a list with the values of my array tasks.

When I inspect the page and go to console I see this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (4:30)
```

I have no idea of what can possibly go wrong but my code looks like the one below:

```
<script type="text/babel">
    var TaskList = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: funtion(){
             return {
                tasks: [
                    {title: 'Clean dishes', id: 1},
                    {title: 'Take out the trash', id: 2},
                    {title: 'Wash the dishes', id: 3}
                ]
            }
        },
        render: function(){
            return(
                <ul>
                    {this.state.tasks.map(function(task){
                        return <Task title={task.title} />
                    }

                    )}
                </ul>
            )
        }
    });
    var Task = function(props){
        return(
            <li>Task: {props.title}</li>
        )
    };
    ReactDOM.render(
        <TaskList />,
        document.getElementById('app')
    )
</script>
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got a typo error:

`getInitialState: function` (instead of `funtion`)